# Scale invariance Vs Conformal invariance

Tags: quantum-field-theory, conformal-field-theory, scale-invariance

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does dilation invariance often imply proper conformal invariance?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6384/why-does-dilation-invariance-often-imply-proper-conformal-invariance)

What exactly is the difference between the two? Can someone give an example of a theory which is scale invariant but not conformally invariant?

Comment: Two counterexamples are e.g. given here http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0006037

Comment: This question is answered [here](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/6384/2451) and hence essentially a duplicate.

Comment: @Qmechanic: the answers to that previous question are now outdated due to some progress over the last two years.