# Are the following terms, related to scale invariance and renormalization in QFT, equivalent?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization, conformal-field-theory, scale-invariance

Which of the following terms are equivalent? and in what cases/limits do the non-equivalent terms become equivalent?

A) a scale invariant quantum field theory.

B) a conformal quantum field theory.

C) a quantum field theory whose bare coupling constants are all dimensionless.

D) a quantum field theory whose physical coupling constants are all dimensionless.

E) a quantum field theory with everywhere-vanishing beta functions.

F) a quantum field theory in a fixed point of the renormalization group flow.

Thanks.

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/6384/2451 and links therein.