# Does scale invariance and R-invariance of Kähler potential imply superconformal symmetry?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, supersymmetry, conformal-field-theory, scale-invariance, superconformality

Consider a four-dimensional $\mathcal{N} = 1$ field theory with Lagrangian:

$ \mathcal{L} = \int d^4 \theta K(\Phi, \bar \Phi) $

and assume $K$ transforms well under dilations with scaling dimension $2$ (so that the action is scale-invariant) and is invariant under R-charge.

Is this sufficient to deduce the theory is conformal (and thus superconformal)? If so, how would this be proven?

Comment: Analogous non-SUSY question: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/6384/2451

Comment: I am aware of the subtlety of the question in the general case, but I'm persuaded SUSY saves the day and $R_K = 0$ is enough to move from dilations to the superconformal group, though I cannot manage a proof.