# Supersymmetric scale invariant non-conformal QFT in 4d

Tags: quantum-field-theory, supersymmetry, conformal-field-theory, scale-invariance

The fact that a QFT in 3+1d is scale invariant does not automatically imply that the QFT is also invariant under the full conformal group, cf. e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/6384/2451) Phys.SE post. Counterexamples are known, but as far as I know are all non-supersymmetric QFTs.

I would like to ask if considering a supersymmetric QFT in 3+1d, scale invariance implies conformal invariance. If yes, what is the argument? If no, what is a known counterexample?

I don't know if the question is studied, or is an open problem.
Second question would be if the answer changes with the ammount of supersymmetry we choose.

Comment: See this paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1302.0884.pdf

Comment: Actually, for non-supersymmetric weakly coupled theories in 3+1d you can prove the IR and UV limits are conformal invariant fixed point; that is scale invariant is inevitably enhanced to conformal. https://arxiv.org/pdf/1204.5221.pdf I don't know if this paper might be useful