# Are all continuous phase transition points describing by conformal field theory?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, conformal-field-theory, phase-transition

How about the dimension? For example the higher dimension (d>2).

If some properties (like critical exponent) of a phase transition point violate the prediction from conformal field theory, does it imply that it can not be a continuous phase transition?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/507102/do-all-classical-statistical-critical-lattice-models-have-emergent-conformal-inv/508097#508097